# How to redirect all HTTPs requests to HTTP

Tags: linux, .htaccess, http, https, centos

I know that people usually ask how to redirect to https, but i have an opposite issue. I check my stats and for a reason that i don't know i get some visits to https:// page, which i don't have.

So my question is how can i redirect all my https requests to http ?

I'm on VPS
Linux version 2.6.32-042stab116.1 , CentOS release 6.7 (Final)

I tried some codes that i find here, but they unfortunately don't work
F.e. this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not really possible. The SSL handshake occurs before any redirects happen, so no redirect will get around that issue. Really your only option is to look into getting a cheap certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you ***can*** force HTTP, you also almost had it correct. Use this in your `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```